# How to deduplicate values within a column without group_by in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I have one column (a) with only two types of values: NULL and TRUE. I want to create 'a_deduplicated' column out of 'a', which is taking the first TRUE value and make the rest NULL. I do not have any other columns to group by it.

Could you please help me to write a code in R to get the 'a_deduplicated' column?

| a | a_deduplicated |
| --- | --- |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| TRUE | TRUE |
| TRUE | NA |
| NA | NA |
| TRUE | TRUE |
| TRUE | NA |
| TRUE | NA |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| TRUE | TRUE |
| TRUE | NA |
| TRUE | NA |
| TRUE | NA |

df to run in R:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(NA, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
                      a_deduplicated = c(NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), 
 row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to Mael's answer, but using the lag function

```r
require(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%  
  mutate(
    new = ifelse(a & is.na(lag(a)), TRUE, NA)
  )

df
#> # A tibble: 15 × 3
#>    a     a_deduplicated new  
#>    <lgl> <lgl>          <lgl>
#>  1 NA    NA             NA   
#>  2 NA    NA             NA   
#>  3 NA    NA             NA   
#>  4 TRUE  TRUE           TRUE 
#>  5 TRUE  NA             NA   
#>  6 NA    NA             NA   
#>  7 TRUE  TRUE           TRUE 
#>  8 TRUE  NA             NA   
#>  9 TRUE  NA             NA   
#> 10 NA    NA             NA   
#> 11 NA    NA             NA   
#> 12 TRUE  TRUE           TRUE 
#> 13 TRUE  NA             NA   
#> 14 TRUE  NA             NA   
#> 15 TRUE  NA             NA

require(waldo)
#> Lade nötiges Paket: waldo
waldo::compare(df$a_deduplicated, df$new)
#> ✔ No differences
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @maike. I actually tried to use the lag function to get it work, but couldn't. But now I understand why mind was not working. Thanks again!

Comment: I was actually doing it like this: df <- df %>%  
  mutate(a_dedup = ifelse(is.na(lag(a)), TRUE, NA))

Comment: the difference with your code is that I did miss putting 'a &' before  'is.na(lag(a))'. What does this  'a &' do? Appreciate if you enlighten me on this.

Comment: sure, happy to: it translates to: if 'a' is TRUE but the row before is not (i.e. lag(a) is NA) then put TRUE. feel free to have a look at df <- df %>%  
  mutate(
    lag = lag(a),
    new = ifelse(a & is.na(lag(a)), TRUE, NA)
  )

Comment: ok gotcha. That made absolute sense. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```r
transform(df, a_new = ifelse(a & is.na(diff(c(0, a))), T, NA))

      a a_deduplicated a_new
1    NA             NA    NA
2    NA             NA    NA
3    NA             NA    NA
4  TRUE           TRUE  TRUE
5  TRUE             NA    NA
6    NA             NA    NA
7  TRUE           TRUE  TRUE
8  TRUE             NA    NA
9  TRUE             NA    NA
10   NA             NA    NA
11   NA             NA    NA
12 TRUE           TRUE  TRUE
13 TRUE             NA    NA
14 TRUE             NA    NA
15 TRUE             NA    NA
```

Comment: This is working perfect as well :) I don't know how this 'transform' function does that magic but it's very quick and nice. Thanks a lot @Maël.

Comment: `transform` is a function that creates a column, it's equivalent to dplyr's mutate.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)
df[, flag:=shift(a,1,type="lag")]
df[, dedup:=ifelse(is.na(flag) & a == TRUE,a,NA)]
df


       a a_deduplicated flag dedup
 1:   NA             NA   NA    NA
 2:   NA             NA   NA    NA
 3:   NA             NA   NA    NA
 4: TRUE           TRUE   NA  TRUE
 5: TRUE             NA TRUE    NA
 6:   NA             NA TRUE    NA
 7: TRUE           TRUE   NA  TRUE
 8: TRUE             NA TRUE    NA
 9: TRUE             NA TRUE    NA
10:   NA             NA TRUE    NA
11:   NA             NA   NA    NA
12: TRUE           TRUE   NA  TRUE
13: TRUE             NA TRUE    NA
14: TRUE             NA TRUE    NA
15: TRUE             NA TRUE    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
df <- structure(list(a = c(NA, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
                      a_deduplicated = c(NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), 
 row.names = c(NA, -15L))

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(a)) %>% 
  mutate(res = if_else(row_number() == 1, a, NA), .keep = c("unused")) %>% 
  select(-grp) %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#>      grp a_deduplicated res  
#>    <int> <lgl>          <lgl>
#>  1     1 NA             NA   
#>  2     1 NA             NA   
#>  3     1 NA             NA   
#>  4     2 TRUE           TRUE 
#>  5     2 NA             NA   
#>  6     3 NA             NA   
#>  7     4 TRUE           TRUE 
#>  8     4 NA             NA   
#>  9     4 NA             NA   
#> 10     5 NA             NA   
#> 11     5 NA             NA   
#> 12     6 TRUE           TRUE 
#> 13     6 NA             NA   
#> 14     6 NA             NA   
#> 15     6 NA             NA

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, res := ifelse(seq(.N) == 1, a, NA), by = rleid(a)][]
#>        a a_deduplicated  res
#>  1:   NA             NA   NA
#>  2:   NA             NA   NA
#>  3:   NA             NA   NA
#>  4: TRUE           TRUE TRUE
#>  5: TRUE             NA   NA
#>  6:   NA             NA   NA
#>  7: TRUE           TRUE TRUE
#>  8: TRUE             NA   NA
#>  9: TRUE             NA   NA
#> 10:   NA             NA   NA
#> 11:   NA             NA   NA
#> 12: TRUE           TRUE TRUE
#> 13: TRUE             NA   NA
#> 14: TRUE             NA   NA
#> 15: TRUE             NA   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much @Yuriy Saraykin for taking the time to do it for me using two different libraries. Learned a lot from this. Thanks again!